# Reinstalling node and npm

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, npm-install

I want to make a clean reinstall of node and npm.
For that, after removing the old software, I did:

```
brew install node
```

But at the end I got this message:

```
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
```

And then, I keep getting this:

```
$ brew postinstall node
==> Postinstalling node
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
```

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: What's the output with --debug ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the output with --debug"?
"brew --debug" ? That does not seem to exist.

Comment: `brew install node --debug`

Comment: OK, I tried. But I get an error.
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local

Comment: I ended up by giving up using brew. I used the package from the NodeJS website (https://nodejs.org/en/) to reinstall. And it now works.